# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - Grub Customizer messed up my Grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, themes, thinkpad

On 20.04 Focal I was trying out the same dual boot Grub Theme I have on my 27" IdeaCentre on my ThinkPad X1 Carbon.
Problem is, the fonts were displaying billboard sized off the screen on the ThinkPad.
Both have 2560x1440p Touchscreens.
I've tried changing it with Grub Customizer and now I have a long pause with a blank screen and it just boots into Ubuntu. I attempted some standard Grub repairs but nothing happens.
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

I tried reinstalling the Blur Grub 2 Theme, nothing.
I tried with Grub Customizer, nothing.

Any recommendations would be appreciated.
I think it may have to do with having the scaling enabled on my ThinkPad when I customized it?

Comment: if it just boots into ubuntu, during the long pause press shift or esc. Also try editing /etc/default/grub and run ````update-grub```` after.

Comment: Did you ignore the warning message that the grub customizer gives when customizing?

Comment: I was able to reduce my custom resolution from 2560x1440 to 1920x1080 in Customizer. I did try reducing the font sizes etc.. with it. I got it back by disabling and enabling the menu on the General tab. I just hate the @ symbols all around the menu and the resolution is like barely 640x480 with the appearance for some reason. I tried a different grub theme from pling.com. Same thing though, the fonts are huge for no good reason. It's like Grub keeps forcing extremely low resolution on the 2560x1440 screen. I don't get it. I'm not doing anything that complicated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have overdone it and done something that the resolution of the grub menu can't handle. Did you see the following warning and ignore it? Anyway, follow the instructions in this image to solve the issue.
[image: Warning]